# writing a parametric equation in a new form

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, coefficients

I have an equation which contains lots of terms with lots of unknown parameters. I want to write it in the form:

```
eq= s^3(something) + s^2(something else) + s(another thing) + constant;
```

I mean,  I need to find "something", "something else" , "another thing" and "constant".

Could anyone help?

Comment: try CoefficientList[eq,s]

Answer (score 3):

```
Collect[(s^3 + 6 s^2 + s + 5) (a^4 + b + 4), s]
```

> ```
> 5 (4 + a^4 + b) + (4 + a^4 + b) s + 6 (4 + a^4 + b) s^2 + (4 + a^4 + b) s^3
> ```

Comment: `Collect[expr, s, Simplify]` is also possible, if you're feeling fancy.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer traditional form.

In:

```
Collect[(s^3 + 6 s^2 + s + 5) (a^4 + b + 4), s] // TraditionalForm
```

Out:

```
s^3 (a^4+b+4)+6 s^2 (a^4+b+4)+s (a^4+b+4)+5 (a^4+b+4)
```